# How to add one linker flag to R CMD SHLIB?

Tags: r

I am programmatically calling `R CMD SHLIB` via `system2()` within R. I would like the linker to link against one additional `.so` file, but I'd like to avoid modifying `PKG_LIBS` in `Makevars`. When I try passing the `.so` file path as an argument to `R CMD SHLIB`, all other linker flags are dropped, as documented in ss. 5.5 of the [Writing R Extensions Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects):

> Supplying linker commands as arguments to R CMD SHLIB will take precedence over PKG_LIBS in Makevars.

Is there a way to tell `R CMD SHLIB` to add one additional flag (rather than replace all flags)?

Alternatively, is there a clean programmatic way to retrieve all current flags so that I can add one by hand? Something like `--get-linker-flags` below:

```
linker_flags <- system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', '--get-linker-flags'),
                        stdout = TRUE)
linker_flags <- paste(linker_flags, '/path/to/my_library.so')
system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', 'my_file.cpp', '-o', 'my_file.so', linker_flags))
```

I've also tried to nonintrusively append an environment variable to the `PKG_VARS` in my `Makevars`:

```
- PKG_VARS = ...existing vars...
+ PKG_VARS = ...existing vars... $(PKG_VARS)
```

and then `Sys.setenv(PKG_VARS = '/path/to/my_library.so')` before calling `R CMD SHLIB`, but this did not work.

Comment: I removed the Rcpp tag as you insist on doing this without Rcpp tooling.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. I agree we should probably be using Rcpp tooling.

Comment: Look into how some package create plugins. Is probably what you want.  In the simplest case case it is just a single statement as seen [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/72dfb68bede9d37e9f94f6845198ec54f3808e9d/R/Attributes.R#L520-L524).   I don't have a good example off the top of my head for an add-on package, but it should not be hard.

Answer (score 0):

> I am programmatically calling R CMD SHLIB via system2() within R.

I would call that "doing it wrong" -- doing it is inherently platform-dependent (.so vs .dll vs .dylib). So we first offered the (still working, of course) [inline](https://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package to help.

After that came [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

And for any real work, please consider creating a package.

As for

> Is there a way to tell R CMD SHLIB to add one additional flag (rather than replace all flags)?

yes because you have both `=` and `+=`, besides which you have `CXXFLAGS` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS`.

Lastly, for Rcpp we use plugin to govern that behaviour.

*Edit:* But if you really must:

```
R> flgs <- tools::Rcmd("config CXXFLAGS", TRUE)
R> flgs
[1] "-g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -march=native"
R> paste(flgs, "-fopenmp")
[1] "-g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -march=native -fopenmp"
R>
```

You could now pass that on to `CXXFLAGS` for `Sys.setenv`. Ditto for `LIBS`:

```
R> libs <- tools::Rcmd("config --ldflags", TRUE)
R> paste(libs, "-fopenmp")
[1] "-Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -fopenmp"
R>
```

Comment: Also note the use of `tools::Rcmd()` -- only learned about that one recently.  Probably preferable to putzing around with `system2()`.

Comment: Actually, `R CMD config --ldflags` misses some libraries in `PKG_LIBS`, so I am still stuck.

Comment: Well as I said: you _probably_ want a `src/Makevars` anyway.

Comment: And besides that every variables in R;s `Makeconf` should be queriable via `R CMD config THATVARHERE`.